# pymc5 - findig aic|bic|loo for model comparison

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc

I have run a bayesian model (regression) using pymc5.
I would like to get a score indicator (AIC|BIC or LOO) to compare different models.
I am a newcomer to pymc and I don't understand how to get this indicator.
For reference here the basic code:

```
# bayes model
basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:
    
    cost = pm.Normal("cost", mu = 0, sigma=2)
    
    a= pm.Normal('a_array', mu=0, sigma=2)
    b = pm.Normal('b_array', mu=0, sigma=2)
    c= pm.HalfNormal('c_array', sigma=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = cost + a* a_array + b* b_array + c*c_array
    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=y_array)
    

with basic_model:
    # draw 1000 posterior samples
    idata = pm.sample(1000)
```

I tried this code:

```
f_logp = basic_model.compile_logp()
# k is the total number of estimated parameters
k = sum(list(map(len, map_est.values())))
aic  = 2 * k - 2 * f_logp(map_est)
```

but it doesn't work (len() of unsized object)

Could anyone help me?
All the best

Comment: I think pymc is now just referred to as that. For version 3 it was called pymc3, but now it's just referred to as pymc. You could specify pymc v5 if you think that's relevant to your question.

Comment: In general AIC or BIC are not recommended for Bayesian models. LOO is a better choice and you can compute it as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76035582/815542, ArviZ also provides WAIC, but LOO provides equivalent results while being more robust and having better diagnostics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get pymc to compute the log likelihood, and then [Arviz](https://python.arviz.org/) for calculating the metrics:

```py
import arviz as az

with basic_model:
    # draw 1000 posterior samples
    idata_01 = pm.sample(1000)

with basic_model:
    pm.compute_log_likelihood(idata_01)

# for loo
basic_model_loo = az.loo(idata_01)
```

or alternatively passing `idata_kwargs={"log_likelihood": True}` to `sample`:

```py
with basic_model:
    # draw 1000 posterior samples
    idata_01 = pm.sample(1000, idata_kwargs={"log_likelihood": True})

# for loo
basic_model_loo = az.loo(idata_01)
```

See the the [pymc documentation](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/stable/learn/core_notebooks/model_comparison.html#leave-one-out-cross-validation-loo) for more information on model comparison.